# What's the verb for "To blur up the water"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Imagine you dropped your keys into the river, you're standing in it, able to see the bottom, looking for your keys. And then your friend John jumps in, and since his impact raised up the sand from the bottom of the river, you can't see anything anymore, so, what did John do? Blurred up the water? Or what do you call this action?

Comment: You can say that John "muddied the water" and this can be used [figuratively](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/muddy_the_waters).

Comment: "Cloud" is another option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps "Roil" is the word you are looking for. Albeit, I have never heard this before.

***roil***

> to make turbid by stirring up the sediment or dregs of

[-Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roil)

Comment: Hi Jeremy, welcome to EL&U. This is a good start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *roil* (linked to the source) and perhaps some examples of its use. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Hi Chappo. No worries, this will be the last time I offer an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The expression I'd use is "**cloud** (up) the water":

> make or become less clear or transparent.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cloud)</sub>

For example:

- > The high winds clouded up the water in area lakes and bays making for tough fishing conditions.  — [Houma Today](https://www.houmatoday.com/sports/20041202/december-brings-change-in-saltwater-fishing-pattern)
- > U could use the sponge filter first, as the sand is clouding up the water, because the sponge wont break, and then once the sands all settled then you can switch to the hang-on with no problems! :) — [do i need a filter](http://www.aquaticcommunity.com/aquariumforum/archive/index.php/t-81965.html)

Answer (score 2):

**to muddy**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/muddy) literal

> make turbid “muddy the water”

As in:

John **muddied** the water.

Answer (score -1):

**Mussed up**

You could say ‘John mussed up the water’. It means to make messy, it includes the idea of ‘roil’, it’s often used for messy hair, it has a sense of movement, with messiness.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mussed

Comment: Could you provide an example of "muss" being applied to water? I've only ever heard it applied to hair, people, or in generic phrases like *no muss, no fuss*. I'd find it strange to be applied to water.